# Deserialize .net object into XML with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a class used to deseralize a .net object.  I'm trying to get the root XML to come out like this:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd"
  xmlns:ns5="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityGoals/v1"
  xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/UserProfile/v2"
  xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ProfileExtension/v1">
```

The XmlRoot of my class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="TrainingCenterDatabase",Namespace=Declarations.SchemaVersion,IsNullable=false),Serializable]
public class TrainingCenterDatabase : com.trainerroad.garmin.TrainingCenterDatabase_t
{

    public TrainingCenterDatabase() : base()
    {
    }
}

public struct Declarations
{
    public const string SchemaVersion = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2";
}
```

And outputs this:

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

How do I add the extra namespaces to my XmlRoot?

Comment: Why do you need the namespaces to be on the root? It shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So I don't have to put them on each element.  Saves a lot of space that way.

Comment: Is the amount of space actually important? Really? You know it's important because you measured it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, it is important.  Saves around 1 meg per file.  Users will have over 100 files.

Comment: Zipping the resulting file would be a better way to safe file space.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This conversation is off topic.  I don't feel I have to explain my use case in order to justify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but you can use custom serialize method if it is really important to save space or traffic